# How to create responsive video (HTML5) background?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-video

I came across this site: https://hinge.co/ and tried to follow the HTML/CSS to find out how they have the fluid, responsive HTML5 video background.

I came across several properties which I don't understand, for example:

```
max-width: calc(177.778vh);
height: calc(56.25vw);
```

I understand this is a JS plugin they're using, and the values in calc are dynamic. But why would the vh height be more than 100? Wouldn't that be bigger than the viewport itself? The video seems to be the exact viewport size so I don't understand the logic here.

Has someone created something like this before and can help understand how this is done?

Comment: `calc()` is CSS method and vh is relative length CSS unit wich represent `Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport`.

Comment: More than 100 overflows the container, which if overflow is set to `hidden` essentially zooms in on the video. It fills your viewport so you think it is perfect edge to edge but really the source video is larger than your screen so you are seeing a zoomed in version.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the code and those two particular lines are not doing much more than constraining how zoomed in the video should be.

What does the trick is

```
min-height: 100vh;
min-width: 177.77vh;
```

which guarantees the video will cover the entire screen and more, regardless of the videos size/shape (vertical or horizontal).

Answer (score 0):

> I came across this site: https://hinge.co/ and tried to follow the HTML/CSS to find out how they have the fluid, responsive HTML5 video background.

They didn't use the HTML5 video element. They embedded the video from Vimeo then positioned it with the CSS.

---

> I understand this is a JS plugin they're using, and the values in calc
>   are dynamic. But why would the vh height be more than 100?

They probably did it to keep the aspect ratio of the video correct in any screen size.

---

> Wouldn't
>   that be bigger than the viewport itself? The video seems to be the
>   exact viewport size so I don't understand the logic here.

It overflows the wrapper. Which has overflow as hidden.

---

Similar Example: https://startbootstrap.com/snippets/video-header/ (Not exactly same but HTML5 Video Element used here for video background)

HTML Video element on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video